# How to integrate custom css to fckeditor?

Tags: php, fckeditor

Can anyone say

How to integrate custom css file to fckeditor or

which are the files need to edit and how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default fckeditor uses editor/css/fck_editorarea.css

In your init you can set: FCKConfig.EditorAreaCSS = '/youstylesheet.css' ;

you can also use an xml file to define certain properties to your elements, see: http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Configuration/Styles

Comment: thanks for your reply

i have placed  my css file ie test.css  in the same location of  fck_editorarea.css and changed the fckconfig.js's FCKConfig.EditorAreaCSS 

but there is no change.Is anything more i need to do? i need to edit the fckstyles.xml ?

Comment: it depends on how you have wrote your CSS.
I noticed that when I tried to plug in a custom CSS I had to make it less selective, by that I mean rather then do .parentCnt .childCnt .p, I had to target my elements directly like .p. Try and remove the "chain" as majority of the time you wont be adding all them tags in your editor. Hope that makes sense.

Secondly, clear your cache, another thing that used to annoy me thinking why its not working.

Comment: exactly wat PHPology says, i saw something about the css file need to be in de fckeditor folder, don't know if that's true.